# Why “Set based approaches” are better than the “Procedural approaches”?

Tags: t-sql

I am very eager to know the real cause though earned some knowledge from [googling](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SetAndProceduralSQL.aspx).

Thanks in adavnce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because SQL is a really poor language for writing procedural code, and because the SQL engine, storage, and optimizer are designed to make it efficient to assemble and join sets of records.

Answer (score 4):

(Note that this isn't just applicable to SQL Server, but I'll leave your tags as they are)

Because, in general, the hundreds of man-years of development time that have gone into the database engine and optimizer, and the fact that it has access to real-time statistics about the data, have resulted in it being better than the user in working out the best way to process the data, for a given request.

Therefore by saying what we **want** to achieve (with a set-based approach), and letting it decide **how** to do it, we generally achieve better results than by spelling out exactly **how** to provess the data, line by line.

For example, suppose we have a simple inner join from table A to table B. At design time, we generally don't know 'which way round' will be most efficient to process: keep a list of all the values on the A side, and go through B matching them, or vice versa. But the query optimizer will know at runtime both the numbers of rows in the tables, and also the most recent statistics may provide more information about the values themselves. So this decision is obviously better made at runtime, by the optimizer.

Finally, note that I have put a number of 'generally's in this post - there will always be times when we know better than the optimizer will, and for such times we can provide hints (`NOLOCK` etc).

Answer (score 2):

Because using a set-based approach to SQL development conforms to the design of the data model.  SQL is a very set-based language, used to build sets, subsets, unions, etc, from data.  Keeping that in mind while developing in TSQL will generally lead to more natural algorithms.  TSQL makes many procedural commands available that don't exist in plain SQL, but don't let that switch you to a procedural methodology.

This makes me think of one of my favorite quotes from Rob Pike in *Notes on Programming C*:

> Data dominates. If you have chosen the right data structures and organized things well, the algorithms will almost always be self-evident. Data structures, not algorithms, are central to programming.

SQL databases and the way we query them are largely set-based.  Thus, so should our algorithms be.

From an even more tangible standpoint, SQL servers are optimized with set-based approaches in mind.  Indexing, storage systems, query optimizers, and other optimizations made by various SQL database implmentations will do a much better job if you simply tell them the data you need, through a set-based approach, rather than dictating how you want to get it procedurally.  Let the SQL engine worry about the best way to get you the data, you just worry about telling it what data you want.

Answer (score 2):

Set based approaches are declarative, so you don't describe the way the work will be done, only what you want the result to look like. The server can decide between several strategies how to complay with your request, and hopefully choose one that is efficient.

If you write procedural code, that code will at best be less then optimal in some situation.

Answer (score 1):

As each one has explained, let the SQL engine help you, believe, it is very smart.
If you do not use to write set based solution and use to develop procedural code, you will have to spend some time until write well formed set based solutions. This is a barrier for most people. A tip if you wish to start coding set base solutions is, stop thinking what you can do with rows, and start thinking what you can do with collumns, and do practice functional languages.